# Spring DirtiesContext for MongoDB

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

I am creating JUnit tests for Spring-Data JPA and Spring-Data-Mongo repositories (each class contains tests for only one repository). To clean up the database before each test is executed I am using DirtiesContext:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```

For JPA (Postgres or H2 DB) it works fine so for each test I get a clean database. But it does not work correctly for MongoDB - the database is not recreated before each test. I know I can use:

```
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @After
    public void clearCollection() {
        mongoTemplate.dropCollection(DocHeader.class);
    }
```

But I want to understand why it works for Postgres or H2 but not for Mongo.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring test infrastructure by default re-uses the application context created for tests when they use the same configuration.

`@DirtiesContext` marks the application context as dirty, i.e. in some way changed by the test (or in your case be the previous test) and therefore a new application context is created.

This will include creating a new `DataSource` for the database.

**With H2 in-memory databases**, creating a new `DataSource` (and dropping the old one before) will actually remove the database and create a new one. This behavior can be configured through JDBC-URL parameters. See http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#embedded_databases for details.

**With *normal* databases** dropping and recreating `Connection`s/`DataSource`s does nothing to the database and your data and schema will be unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So now the question is why it works for PostgreSQL. For PostgreSQL database data is refreshed when context is marked as dirty. So it works exactly the same way as Mongo. But for Mongo it does not work. Do you know why?

Comment: I suppose it works for Postgres because in application properties I am using   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop. If I change this mode to update then data is not removed (and schema is not regenerated) even I have DirtiesContext set. Right now I am thinking is there similar option for Mongo?